# Read Info.plist from prefix.pch

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, plist, info.plist

Is it possible to read a value from my Info.plist file in the prefix.pch file and sat a macro according to that value?

For instance, if I have a boolean property in the Info.plist called `UseSomeResource` I would like to make a `#define USE_SOME_RESOURCE 1` if the value of that property is YES.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory yes, albeit I don't think the .pch is the best place to put it. I'd suggest placing this macro within a `Macros.h`, or some similar mechanism, that you import within your .pch

```
#define USE_SOME_RESOURCE ([[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"UseSomeResource"] boolValue])
```

[More about .pch can be read here](http://www.cimgf.com/2010/05/02/my-current-prefix-pch-file/)

It's worth noting that this will still determine the value at runtime, not at compile time. If you want it to be run at compile time, you may need to write a script as part of one of your build phases, that reads the Info.plist, and creates a header file, which is then included as part of your project. This seems like quite a roundabout method, and as such I highly suggest the runtime alternative.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. And also, you already answered my next question regarding if this was done at runtime or compile-time. This macro was supposed to replace an existing solution where we read the value of the `UseSomeResource` property from within our classes. The idea was to have a `#ifdef` macro so that our execution wasn't poluted with unnecessary checks. But does this even make sense? I mean, `#ifdef` is invoked at compile-time, so I am guessing that I cannot use it with a value that is determined at run-time. Anyway, if this is done a run-time I may stick to the current solution.

Comment: And just out of curiosity, why would you place this macro in a hader file which you import into the .pch in stead of doing it in there directly?

Comment: Personal preference, there's nothing stopping you from putting it in directly. It's more to keep the code a bit more tidy, if there's something going wrong with the macros, I know to check the macros header file; not have to discover that they're actually contained within the .pch.